# How to pass the data to route using jquery in Laravel

Tags: php, jquery, laravel, routes

I have a route like this

```
Route::get('user/{id}/article', 'ArticleController@show')->name('Show');
```

And need to pass the parameter id using jquery

```
$('.user').click(function() {
  var id = $(this).attr('data-id');
  window.location.href ='{{ route('Show',['id'=> id]) }}';
});
```

But `id` can`t be recognized , How should I do?

Comment: Please give me html code

Answer (score 3):

```
$('.user').click(function() {
    var id = $(this).attr('data-id');
    var url = '{{ route("Show", ":id") }}';
    url = url.replace(':id', id);
    window.location.href = url;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can pass value like the below code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
           $('#modal-save').on('click',function(){
                $.ajax({
                   type : 'post',
                       url : urlEdit,
                      data : {body : $('#post-body').val(), postId: postId , _token:token }
              }).done(function(msg){
                //console.log(msg.new_body);
                  $(PostBodyElement).text(msg['new_body']);
                  $('#edit-modal').modal('hide');
        });
    });
```

This should be in your controller

```
public function postEditPost(Request $request)
                    {
                     $this->validate($request,[
                      'body' => 'required'
                        ]);
                       $post = Post::find($request['postId']);
                     if(Auth::user() != $post->user)
                         {
                         return redirect()->back();
                        }
                     $post->body = $request['body'];
                   $post->update();
                         return response()->json(['new_body' => $post->body],200);
                }
```

And in your route :

```
 Route::post('/edit',[
              'uses' => 'PostController@postEditPost',
              'as' => 'edit'
                  ]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to generate your html link like this

```
<a href="user/{{ $user->id }}/article">{{ $user->name }}</a>
```

Comment: Is it have a possible to call the route by name? Not using the url.

Comment: Yes, but plz explain me url which you want.